# Convert double to unsigned integer in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, data-conversion, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to convert a double into an unsigned int in Java.

With unsigned int I mean the range from 0 to 4294967295.
I use `int` as carrier - and it can be converted to a String with [`Integer.toUnsignedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString(int)).

I don't care what result I get if

- The double is `NaN`.
- The double is `Inf` or `-Inf`
- The double is outside of the range: `< 0` or `> 4294967295`.

As long as I get **any** result.

A simple cast does not work:

```
(int) 4294967295d == 2147483647
(int) 2147483648d == 2147483647
```

So the problematic range is `2147483648d` - `4294967295d`.

Is there a fast way to cover that range correctly?

**tl;dr**: In C I would use `(unsigned int) dblValue` - what would I use in Java for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `4294967295f`

That's not a thing. That float does not exist. It gets rounded. Don't use floats, there's almost no point to them. It works as a double.

> Is there a fast way to cover that range correctly?

Once you realize that your question makes no sense and move to doubles instead, yeah. Cast to long, cast to int:

```
double d = 4294967295.0;
int i = (int) (long) d;
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(i));
> -1
> 4294967295
```

Comment: Sorry about the `f` part - fixed it in my question.

Comment: But ok, that's  `D2L` followed by `L2I`, if I can guess the bytecode correctly. Not sure what the JIT will make out of that - but seems simple enough.

Comment: JIT will most likely optimize that completely if needed. But mostly, I just don't know of a way to do this with 1 byte worth of bytecode, I thought 2 was a pretty decent score :P